# Custom Window Title with customer adpter

Tags: android, adapter

unable to set  Custom Window Title in Android when using my customer adapter. 
I did all what said on this web

http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-custom-window-title-in-android/

but I dont know where to put this:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.window_title);
```

my code on my main activity look like this:

```
ListRssAdpter listAdapter;
ListView lv = getListView();
lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
listAdapter = new ListRssAdpter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, listKeys);
getResources().getString(R.string.emtyRssList),0).show();
lv.setAdapter(listAdapter); // on test
```

thanks for the help

Comment: I don't understand why you speak about Adapter. The code has to be put in the onCreate method of the Activity, no matter there is an adapter or not. Or I miss something?

Comment: If I write the code its just the same gui as was before.can't see any change...

Comment: Please provide your style.xml and layout.xml, and the manifest.